# Locked phone connected to the net with blocked SIM

Tags: security, internet, locked-out

I got my phone stollen today. I contacted my phone company and blocked the SIM card. I tested it by trying to call the phone and was denied.

However, using Whatsapp and K9 (with gmail), I could see that the phone was connected to the net a few hours later. Should I assume that the robber somehow managed to get passed the locking pattern? Or are there any other way to do it?

Note, the phone was only connecting to known WiFi, and not to open one.

---

Edit: Whatsapp, use tickles to indicate when a message was received. And K9 is a mail client. I could see on my gmail account, that the last IMAP sync (probably automatic) was made hours after the phone was stollen. The combination of those means that somehow the phone was on-line.

I used my phone with my home WLAN. And a few others. But the phone was not actively looking for WiFi to connect to. So it should not automatically connect to an open WiFi.

Comment: `blocked the SIM card` You may also inform the IMEI number(s) of the device to the network company so that the robber cannot use any other SIM in it. // `I could see that the phone was connected to the net a few hours later.` Can you please how you saw that by editing your question? What is K9? // `Note, the phone was only connecting to known WiFi` You mean, your phone connected to your own/any other saved WiFi network after being stolen?

Comment: There is another possibility like they changed and used their own SIM card with mobile data (which is unlikely, but still possible).

Comment: @GokulNC, I edited in some details. I hope that covers your questions?

Comment: @AndrewT., yeah, that would probably work... I have no idea about the profesionalism of the robber, so no option could be discarded...